# Remove specific words within lines

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, word-processing

I have a text file that has something like this:

```
loginName:  Name1   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/ (KHTML like Gecko)  Chrome/61.0.3163.104    OpenFin/9.61.31.74
loginName:  Name2   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/ (KHTML like Gecko)  Chrome/61.0.3163.112
loginName:  Name3   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/ (KHTML like Gecko)  Chrome/61.0.3163.105    OpenFin/9.61.31.78
loginName:  Name4   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/ (KHTML like Gecko)  Chrome/61.0.3163.100
```

Some has only `Chrome/X.X.X.X` and others have `Chrome/X.X.X.X  OpenFin/X.X.X.X`

The ones that only have `Chrome/X.X.X.X`, I want to leave them alone. The ones that include `OpenFin/X.X.X.X`, I want to remove `Chrome/X.X.X.X` from those lines.

I tried the following but had no luck.

```
sed 's/Chrome*.*OpenFin/OpenFin/' filename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by modifying to the following:

```
sed 's/Chrome.*OpenFin/OpenFin/' filename
```